# wither vs builder Lombok library

Tags: java, builder, lombok

I have started using the Lombok library, and I am unable to figure out the difference between using a wither & a builder.

```
@Builder
@Wither
public class Sample {
   private int x;
   private int y;
}
```

Now I can create an object in 2 ways:

```
Sample s = new Sample().builder()
              .x(10)
              .y(15)
              .build();
```

OR

```
Sample s = new Sample()
           .withx(10)
           .withy(10);
```

What is the difference between the two? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, the difference is when you build a object with builder(), you must call build() method at last, and before you call build(), all property values are saved in the internal builder object instead of the object your created with new. After you setted all properties and call build(), a new object will be created. See details here: https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html . I think the better way for builder pattern is:

```
Sample s = Sample.builder()
          .x(10)
          .y(15)
          .build();
```

Because the first Sample object is redundant.

For withers, every time you called withXXX(xxx), a new object is returned, with XXX set to xxx, and all other properties cloned from the object you called wither on (if xxx is different from the original xxx. See details here: https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Wither.html). Choose which way, I think it's only depends on your personal habit and your project's code style.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: So can I assume that with builder, a new object isn't created until all the values are set correctly. Whereas with wither, the object is created at the beginning and if input is incorrect, will need for GC to clear it.

Comment: @user1692342 Yes, with builder, only the builder object is created and the Sample object will created at last. You can get more details from the internal implementation in lombok. :)

Comment: I don't think It's just a matter of taste. Please see the @Roel Spilker's answer below.

Comment: "Because the first Sample object is redundant." there the OP creates a new object first, which often I believe with builder pattern the constructor would tend to be private, and an empty constructor which was used there would not be exposed, am I correct?

Answer (score 25):

`@Builder` is used to create mutable objects, `@Wither` for immutables.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: Is/was there a particular reason to chose for immutable objects for wither? It would be nice to call them like `Sample s = new Sample().withX(10).withY(15);`